# C programming - exit status printing

Tags: c, status, child-process, exitstatus

I am new in C programming and was asked to write a simple program with these requirements:

- creates a separate process to execute the external program, `doStuff`
- waits for 10 seconds
- sends an `SIGUSR1` signal to the child process, and
- obtains and prints the exit status of the child process.

I do not really have the `doStuff` with me.

I am not sure how to meet the last requirement, should I use `waitpid()`? I haven't learned it yet. May I know how to apply that to my program as

Here is the code I did, I know is simple so I am not sure did I do it rightly. May anyone can kindly let me know am I doing it on the right direction?

Thank you so much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "doStuff.h"
// which inculde the funcion "doStuff"

int main()
{
    doStuff();

    sleep(10);

    signal(SIGUSR1, doStuff);


}
```

Comment: You need to use `fork()`, `exec()`, and `wait()`.

Comment: Also look the status returned contains extra data. You should use `wexitstatus`.

Comment: Which of [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html),
[`execv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html) and either 
[`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) or 
[`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) is giving problems?  What problems?  There are a myriad related questions on SO.